# HSL stream Video stretched after some time on IOS 15

Tags: ios, swift5, http-live-streaming, azure-media-services

First, this is a Youtube link showing the problem:  [Video stretched](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7yGT4GRdJXI). The Youtube video is edited to remove unnecessary parts, I am only showing the important parts. As you can see after some time the video gets stretched.

- The original video was uploaded to Azure media services and encoded by Azure media using the built-in "AdaptiveStreaming" preset.
- I am using HLS dynamic packaging with this url:

  - https://amswrdev-usso.streaming.media.azure.net/80a2651c-462f-487f-b1a3-87cb72366255/1zIHQ.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-cmaf)
- I am testing it on an Iphone 12 pro max, IOS 15.0.1, swift 5.0
- I am using the AVPlayerViewController, this is the code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI 
import AVKit 

struct VideoPlayerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable { 
    var player: AVPlayer 
    @Binding var gravity: AVLayerVideoGravity 

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoPlayerView>) -> AVPlayerViewController { 
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController() 
        controller.player = player 
        controller.showsPlaybackControls = false 
        controller.videoGravity = gravity 
        return controller 
    }     

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoPlayerView>) { 
        uiViewController.videoGravity = gravity 
    } 

    func dismantleUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, coordinator: Self.Coordinator) { 
        //print("dismantleUIViewController \(uiViewController)") 
    } 
}
```

My hypothesis:

- Avplayer is not correctly switching to the correct bandwidth
- Azure media is not sending the correct variants on the initial playlist
- Maybe I don't have the correct parameters for preferredMaximumResolution and preferredForwardBufferDuration? but I don't know what values should be correct.
- Dynamic packaging of azure media is now on version 7, maybe is not supported by IOS?

I have been trying to fix it changing my view to have fixed values of height and width but is not working. I have 2 weeks trying to figure out this but nothing is working, Do you have any idea?

Like I said the video is stretched after some time, is not consistent. Sometimes happens immediately and sometimes takes more time but happens.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still on iOS 14 on an iPhone 8 - and it plays just fine for me... so this may be an iOS 15.0.1 issue right now.

Comment: I guess you are right. I had to use the version 4 of HLS dynamic packaging:  format=m3u8-aapl  to fix the problem.  Here the link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/encode-dynamic-packaging-concept#hls-dynamic-packaging

Comment: try the CMAF version again on the official 15.0.1 release on hardware.  I upgraded my iPhone 8 to 15.0.1 and it works fine for me.

Comment: I tried ...but sometimes the audio is playing but the video has blackscreen and the video is stretched.   I am convinced that is not a problem of azure...is about how Avplayer handle CMAF.

For now version 4 is working better than CMAF. Maybe in the future it will works better